# React Native redux-saga - How to achieve yield all when getting a response and saving a separate record

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

Currently I have a piece of code that request an api call and then base from the response:

1. OK
2. Error

I will have to create another pending record this is due to intermittent connection issue so i have to deal with an event that happened and store it and use it later.

```js
const response = yield call(api.login, credentials)

yield all(
            response.matchWith({
                Ok: ({ value }) => {
                    
                    put(Actions.pendingRecord(null))
                    return put(Actions.apiSuccess(value))
                },
                Error: ({ value }) => {
                    
                    const pendingRecord = {
                        value: true,
                        data: {
                            event: "queue"
                            
                        }
                    }
    
                    put(Actions.pendingRecord(pendingRecord))
                    return put(Actions.apiFailure(value))

                }
            })
        )
```

is it possible to have multiple `put` actions when calling `yield all` ?
I'm referring to this:

```js
put(Actions.pendingRecord(null))
return put(Actions.apiSuccess(value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-batched-actions you can do it like that:

```js
return put(batchActions([
  Actions.pendingRecord(null),
  Actions.apiSuccess(value)
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we did something like this, and works well.